# How do I hide the shell_exec() output from the user when running PHP script from SSH?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, ssh, command-line-interface

I have a PHP script that automatically downloads Nginx and setups my web server. It does actions such as: create Nginx configuration files, generate SSL certificates, among other amazing functions. It is ran via SSH, php file.php command.

Unfortunately due to several reasons I will not be posting it here but I will be showing out examples of the issue I'm getting.

For example, a few seconds after I am running the script via the command line interface, I get the following output:

`rm: cannot remove...` (unexisting file)

or I have this code:

`if(!preg_match("/nginx/", shell_exec("nginx -v"))) {`

and it outputs the Nginx version and also shows the output of the `apt-get` command (`shell_exec()`).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

PHP's [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) on `shell_exec()` has comments that address your issues. Basically the issue is that `shell_exec` only saves the output of `stdout` to the variable, and `stderr` is sent directly to the user.

However, I highly recommend that you look into configuration management systems like Puppet or Ansible to perform these tasks. There are far too many security issues in your approach and I think you don't have the knowledge on how to even identify possible issues.